# Using the onclick event on a Div doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

When I click that it will use a JavaScript page which i marked as a note
(      // )
(i also tried with </script)
but it doesn't work, i tried to see even with console.log to see if i can see it worked on console but it doesn't..

So the onclick is not working, if it would i would've see the 1 displayed on console.

```js
function fun() {
  //<script src="checkcheckcheck.js"/>
  console.log("1");
}


var map;
require([
  "esri/map",
  "esri/dijit/LocateButton",
  "dojo/domReady!"
], function(Map, LocateButton) {
  map = new Map("map", {
    center: [-56.049, 38.485],
    zoom: 3,
    basemap: "streets"

  });

  geoLocate = new LocateButton({
    map: map
  }, "LocateButton");
  geoLocate.startup();

  geoLocate.on('locate', (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    var LatM = data.position.coords.latitude;
    var LongM = data.position.coords.longitude;
    localStorage.setItem("yourLocationLat", "LatM");
    localStorage.setItem("yourLocationLong", "LongM");
    console.log(LatM, LongM);
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body,
#esri-map-container {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 800px;
  height: 500px;
}

#LocateButton {
  position: absolute;
  top: 95px;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 50;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.35/esri/css/esri.css">
<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.35/"></script>
<div id="map" class="map">
  <div id="LocateButton" onclick="fun();"></div>
</div>
<div id="valueInsert"></div>
```

my javascript page (checkcheckcheck.js):

```
const pix = 3.141592653589793;
const radius = 6378.16;


function radians(x) {
  return x * pix / 180;
  console.log("2");
}

function calculateDistance(lat1, long1, lat2, long2) {
  let dlon = radians(long2 - long1);
  let dlat = radians(lat2 - lat1);

  let a = (Math.sin(dlat / 2) * Math.sin(dlat / 2)) + Math.cos(radians(lat1)) * Math.cos(radians(lat2)) * (Math.sin(dlon / 2) * Math.sin(dlon / 2));

  let angle = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
  return angle * radius;
  console.log("3");
}

//let yourLocationLat = 32.777777;
//let yourLocationLong = 34.999999;

let places = [{
  "name": "Tel-Aviv",
  "lat": 32.083333,
  "long": 34.7999968
}, {
  "name": "Haifa",
  "lat": 32.81841,
  "long": 34.9885

}, {
  "name": "Rehovot",
  "lat": 31.894756,
  "long": 34.809322
},{
  "name": "Berlin",
  "lat": 52.520008,
  "long": 13.404954
},{
  "name": "Alaska",
  "lat": 66.160507,
  "long": -153.369141

},{
  "name": "Mexico",
  "lat": 19.432608,
  "long": -99.133209
},{
  "name": "Jerusalem",
  "lat": 31.771959,
  "long": 35.217018
}]

let result = []; 
places.forEach((x) => {
  let resultDistance = calculateDistance(localStorage.getItem("yourLocationLat"), localStorage.getItem("yourLocationLong"), x.lat, x.long)
  let obj = {
  "city": x.name,
  "lat": x.lat,
  "long": x.long,
  "distance": resultDistance
  }

  result.push(obj);
})

// shortest first
result.sort((a, b) => {
 return a.distance - b.distance  
 console.log("4");
})

document.getElementById("valueInsert").innerHTML = result[0].city;
```

Comment: `LocateButton`. Use a button not a div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move some of the code into a function and call that function in the locate event

So

```
geoLocate.on('locate', (data) => {
    var LatM = data.position.coords.latitude;
    var LongM = data.position.coords.longitude;
    getDistance(LatM,LongM); // here you call the code you want
});
```

You JS file:

```js
const pix = 3.141592653589793;
const radius = 6378.16;


function radians(x) {
  return x * pix / 180;
  console.log("2");
}

function calculateDistance(lat1, long1, lat2, long2) {
  let dlon = radians(long2 - long1);
  let dlat = radians(lat2 - lat1);

  let a = (Math.sin(dlat / 2) * Math.sin(dlat / 2)) + Math.cos(radians(lat1)) * Math.cos(radians(lat2)) * (Math.sin(dlon / 2) * Math.sin(dlon / 2));

  let angle = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
  return angle * radius;
  console.log("3");
}

//let yourLocationLat = 32.777777;
//let yourLocationLong = 34.999999;

let places = [{
  "name": "Tel-Aviv",
  "lat": 32.083333,
  "long": 34.7999968
}, {
  "name": "Haifa",
  "lat": 32.81841,
  "long": 34.9885

}, {
  "name": "Rehovot",
  "lat": 31.894756,
  "long": 34.809322
}, {
  "name": "Berlin",
  "lat": 52.520008,
  "long": 13.404954
}, {
  "name": "Alaska",
  "lat": 66.160507,
  "long": -153.369141

}, {
  "name": "Mexico",
  "lat": 19.432608,
  "long": -99.133209
}, {
  "name": "Jerusalem",
  "lat": 31.771959,
  "long": 35.217018
}]

function getDistance(lat,long) {

  let result = [];
  places.forEach((x) => {
    let resultDistance = calculateDistance(lat, long , x.lat, x.long)
    let obj = {
      "city": x.name,
      "lat": x.lat,
      "long": x.long,
      "distance": resultDistance
    }

    result.push(obj);
  })

  // shortest first
  result.sort((a, b) => {
    return a.distance - b.distance
    console.log("4");
  })

  document.getElementById("valueInsert").innerHTML = result[0].city;
}
```

Comment: it worked, 
may i ask when i am using this function it does work and in console i see the 1.
but it doesn't actually send me to the other JavaScript page
i tried putting inside the function:
src="checkcheckcheck.js"; which didnt work

it didn't allow me to do it inside another script tag like this:
<script src="checkcheckcheck.js"></script>
do you know why is that?

Comment: but i want to open a js page, when i do this location = "checkcheckcheck.js";
it just open the page as it looks like i right click and did view page source, i want it to open the page and start do the functions inside it once the locate is clicked

Comment: it did load the javescript page now, but it doesnt execute any of the functions there, except for the ending which is document.getElementById("valueInsert").innerHTML = result[0].city;
it is just doing this one, i have put some more console log to see if any of the functions work, but they dont,
is it because of the load thingy? or maybe another problem and it is not relevant to the question i asked you, thanks for you help btw, i appreciate it.

Comment: i apologize, i updated it now, i really didnt think of that..
sorry for delay message

Comment: when i included the file script in the page, it didnt work at all for some reason.
you mean at the begging to make load of the function calculateDistance, and then? but when i click on the locatebtn i get the coords and then from this coords i want to compare it to my already made coords and the functions should return which one i am the closest too

Comment: I simplified the code  - there is no need for localStorage

Comment: hey again sorry for delay respond, i needed a break
i check and it says that getDistance is not defined
the function: fun is still working so i dont know why it says that..

Comment: Scroll down in my answer, I wrapped some of your code in `function getDistance(lat,long) { ... }` You need to include the JS file before the other code is called

Comment: okay so i put the script of the function fun above the first script of map, and also <script src="checkcheckcheck.js"></script> above that so i included the js as u said, and it worked.
thanks!